# Finding a distribution whose KL Divergence from a given distribution is a constant $\alpha$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory

Consider P as a multinomial distribution over k variables. I would like to find a distribution Q, also a multinomial distribution over k variables such that KL Divergence between Q from P is a constant $\alpha$. In short what is the multinomial distribution Q over k variables, such that $D_{KL}(P||Q) = \alpha$. How can I solve for Q? More generally how can I solve for Q if both P and Q are from the same family of distributions and belong to the exponential family.

Comment: Practically, if you need to find any such $Q$ (generally, there are multiple solutions for the first problem), you can use the following optimization problem:

$$\min(D_{KL}(P||Q)-\alpha)^2$$
$$\text{s.t. }\sum_{i=1}^k Q_i=1, \quad Q_i\ge 0, i=1,\dots,k1$$

The result will depend on the initial guess of $Q$...

Comment: For the exponential family, assuming you know $\eta, A, T$, $p = f(x|\theta_1)$, and that you can calculate $\mathbb{E}_p[T(x)]$, the condition would lead to the equation $\alpha = \langle\eta_1 - \eta(\theta), \mathbb{E}_pT(x)\rangle - A_1+A(\theta)$. Saying more would require knowing the family explicitly.

Comment: @stochasticboy321: Thanks please could you elaborate on how you obtained this. Even a pointer to the literature or the general ideas used would be helpful.

Comment: @vvknitk Recall the form of the exponential family - $f(x|\theta) = h(x) \exp (\langle \eta(\theta), T(x)\rangle - A(\theta) )$. Substitute this into the expression for the KL divergence, and a little bit of churning gets you the above.